# What type of dragon is a trickster dragon

Tags: dragonvale

I need a habitat for it because it is taking up room in my hatchery and it was a gift so I don't know

Comment: are you on about the Trick Dragon? I can't find anything about a Trickster dragon.

Answer (score 1):

The Trick dragon can be put in a Plant, Fire or Earth habitat.

[Trick Dragon wiki page](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Trick_Dragon)